Confusion about Riesz representation theorem in $L^p$

Riesz-Representation Theorem (RR): let $(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space. Then for every $T\in H'$, there exists a unique $v_T\in H$ s.t.
$$T(u)=\langle u,v_T \rangle\quad \forall u\in H.$$
The dual space of $H$ is isomorphic to $H$.

I have encountered the following statement, but can not verify it. It looks like an extension of RR:

Dual spaces of $L^p$: The dual space of $L^p$ is isomorphic to $L^q$ for $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$ (i will always use $p,q$ as conjugated exponents in the following). In particular, the dual of $L^2$ (which is a Hilbert space) is isomorphic to itself.

This second statement allows to find unique elements $v_T\in L^q$ that represent elements in $T\in (L^p)'$. How can we find this $v_T$?
Idea: by the fundamental Lemma of calc. of variations, we know that for $u\in L^p$
$$T(u)=\int_\Omega v_T u $$
fixes the value of $v_T\in L^q$ almost everywhere (if $v_T$ is integrable on compact sets, which it is, as a function of $L^q$).
Question: Is this integral the correct way to construct the Riesz-representation of $T$?

Edit: Somebody called @Valere just posted a perfectly fine answer, and removed it again after I asked for some clarifications. I will recreate it from memory:
One can construct $v_T$ as $\displaystyle \frac{u T(u)}{\Vert u\Vert^2}$, based on "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order" from Gilbarg and Trudinger.
I did not understand whether this construction also satisfies my integral representation:
$$T(u)\stackrel{?}{=} \int v_t u = \int\frac{u T(u)}{\Vert u\Vert^2} u = T(u) \frac{\Vert u\Vert^2_{L^2}}{\Vert u\Vert^2} $$
where i think that $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ denotes the $L^p$ norm. So the integral representation would not hold exactly, but I dont see the flaw in my reasoning with the fundamental lemma of calc. of variations.
Is the trick to choose
$$\Vert \cdot \Vert:=\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$$
so that the above representation works out?

I think the problem with this is that this $v_T$ depends on the $u$ that you plug into $T$ which it is not supposed to

For general $p$, this is far more difficult to construct than the representative in $L^2$ (which only needs the projection onto $\mathrm{ker}(T)$).
In Alt - Linear Functional Analysis, this is done using the Radon-Nikodym Thm.: If you have some $F \in L^p(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)'$ and $\lvert \Omega \rvert < \infty$, then you can get a signed Radon-measure $\nu$ by $\nu(E) := F(\chi_E)$ for all $E \in \Sigma$. Then you can choose the representative as the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\tfrac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu} \in L^1(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$. However, it is nontrivial to show that this function actually has the desired properties.
If $\lvert \Omega \rvert = \infty$, things get even more difficult. Then you will have to exhaust $\Omega$ appropriately by subsets with finite measure and choose a limit of all the representatives on these bounded subsets. For this, you need that $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space.

thank you i see this makes sense.
